# How to populate a new 50 cell column in Google sheets with randomly selected data from an existing column?

Tags: google-sheets, random, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I don't have much coding experience and not familiar with Google sheets and am only using it for a specific personal project. The idea is that I have a sheet populated with 50+ responses from a google form and I want to return a random selection of exactly 50 of those responses. The responses from the form take in data that will span to column I, but I only need to randomly return 3 of these columns (say B, E, and H for example) of the winnings responses and have this done 50x without any response being selected more than once. What is the formula I would need to do this? Additionally, as I know the google form responses won't populate the spreadsheet beyond column I, is there a way I can automate this process to take place in column J without having to select 50 cells in column J and then running the formula? I've thought the answer would be somewhere on the internet but I've yet to find anything I can use. Thank you.

As I stated before I don't have much coding experience so I haven't tried working this out myself yet. After looking into it a bit I know I need to use VLOOKUP to get the specific data I need from the 50 winners and perhaps RANDOMARRAY, but beyond that I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sortn()` and `randarray()`, like this:

```
=sortn({B2:B,E2:E,H2:H}, 50, 0, randarray(rows(B2:B)) * sign(len(A2:A)), false)
```

See [sortn()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624) and [randarray()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9211904).

Comment: Thank you so incredibly much, I appreciate this immensely.